# How could make two apps that can communicate with each other?

Tags: android

How can I make two apps communicate with each other. One app would be for the customer end and the other would be for the business end. Any resources/books to get started(for Android)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). One of its [features](https://firebase.google.com/features/) is cloud messaging - deliver and receive messages across platforms reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But, I was wondering if I would be able to share information such as the people who are using the business end app's location with the people who are using the customer end app?